# My dog chewed the surface of my doors, how should I go about fixing this?

Tags: repair, doors

My dog was kept in the bathroom and ended up chewing the surfaces of my 2 doors. What's a good way to go about fixing this to make it look at least decent again?

This is the damage:

[image: Damage]

Comment: LOL, obviously not a rotweiler.

Answer (score 3):

Hollow panel doors like the one in your picture can be purchased at your local home improvement store for relatively cheap, probably in the range of $30-50.  So the easiest thing to do is not fix them and just replace them.

If you are set on repairing it, you should sand down the damage, fill it with wood putty, sand again, the prime and paint (the entire door). With the texture and shape of the door, it is unlikely you could repair this in a manner that is not noticeable.  Just note that the cost of buying the necessary products to repair it are probably more expensive than just replacing it.

Comment: So if I was to replace the door, what if I wanted to keep the door knobs? Would I just take out the current ones and put them on the new door?

Comment: A new door will not come with door knobs, it might not even come with any holes or chiseled out areas for the hinges. The standard procedure is to place the doors on edge next to each other, and copy the location of the hinges and door knob from one door to the other.

Comment: Replacing the door is absolutely the easiest option, but if you don't, I don't think you need to paint the entire door. If that is at the bottom of the door, it should be patchable. *You* may still notice, but likely no one else would.